# SSL error in cakaPHP with extensions=php_openssl uncomment

Tags: cakephp, ssl

I am using cakePHP and I am trying to get locally the profile picture in facebook after logging in using her/his facebook.

Saving is working fine, the only problem that I've been encountering is the SSL error,

```
Warning (2): file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed [APP\Controller\FacebookCpsController.php, line 98]
Warning (2): file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Failed to enable crypto [APP\Controller\FacebookCpsController.php, line 98]
Warning (2): file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/10203572402389803/picture) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: operation failed [APP\Controller\FacebookCpsController.php, line 98]
Warning (2): file_put_contents(/files/user_profile) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory [APP\Controller\FacebookCpsController.php, line 99]
```

My controller name is FacebookCps.

and this is my line 98 and 99:

```
line 98: $image = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$uid.'/picture'); 
line 99: file_put_contents('/files/user_profile', $image);
```

My extension=php_openssl is already uncomment in my php.ini (C:/xampp/php/phpini)

Thank you for any suggestion/help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Janelle Ann Lagatuz As the error says, ".... routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed ..." you should download a certificate bundle. Place it somewhere on web server where you can access it and giving the user permission to read the file. Then try this code:

```
    $arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "cafile" => "/path/to/bundle/ca-bundle.crt",
        "verify_peer"=> true,
        "verify_peer_name"=> true,
    ),
);
```

Their is another approach too, instead of passing the certificate, just put the verify_peer and verify_peer_name as false and pass it as follows (you can see the description of this method here: http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php) :

```
<?php
$arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);  

$image = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$uid.'/picture', false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));

echo $response; ?>
```

But remember, this is not good approach as you are not passing the certificate, this breaks SSL certification and is a security hole.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have a certificate placed in Vendor/Facebook/fb_ca_chain_bundle. Is this certificate fine? I already installed it too.

Comment: $arrContextOptions=array(
     "ssl"=>array(
        "cafile" => "/Vendor/Facebook/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt",
             "verify_peer"=>true,
    "verify_peer_name"=>true,
         )); 
I tried it , but failed to load the crt file, so for now I am using the the other way setting the verify_peer and verify_peer_name to false

Comment: As long as the certificate is valid and accessible to your script, i think you are doing fine. Just a side note, for downloading the certificate bundle, try this : http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Comment: your answer is very helpful, I can now access the certificate and tried to echo the file_get_contents and it has a value, but now the remaining error is failed to open stream: No such file or directory, I do have a folder name user_profile under the file folder, why does it says no such file directory?

Comment: Do you mean, in this argument "cafile" => "/path/to/bundle/ca-bundle.crt", it is saying "failed to open stream: No such file or directory"?

Comment: yes, I downloaded new one named ca-bundled, I didn't use the fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt because it is not working, the new downloaded file is working and placed in C:/xampp/htdocs .. could it be possibly to use it even inside the Vendor?

Comment: @JanelleAnnLagatuz It is working right, awesome. What is this vendor, i didnot understand where this vendor came from?

Comment: Ahh sorry.. I'm using cakephp here and in the tutorials that saw, the base_facebook is placed there inside the Vendor folder.. I am using the Facebook Graph Api

Comment: To be honest, i didnot worked on the Facebook API (file_get_contents with other API i worked on), any way, if you want to place it in vendor i see no problem on it as long as it is accessible with your functions. Just as a side note: please check the read permission of the vendor folder.

Comment: Yes, thank you it is already accessible in the vendor file. Thank you for your great help!